# Getting values from dropdowns and textbox

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I'm working on my first angular project.  I created a form where the user can choose from a dropdown list. I added an option on each drop down to choose "other" and type in a textbox.

This creates a situation where the user could choose values from the dropdown and use the textbox at the same time.  I have a function on my submit button where I need to store the values that the user is passing.

The problem I'm having is that if the user selected from the dropdown, the value is an ID value but the textbox returns a name. Also, I'm not sure how to handle the values because my backend API is expecting four text values.  If the user has two dropdown entries and two textbox entries, what's a good way to get the right values to the API?

I thought about passing every possible value into the function but I'm not sure what sort of logic I could add to only get the 4 values I need.

```
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="Country">Category:</label><!--<input type="text" #category (change)="CountryTextAreaFilled(category.value)">-->
      <select *ngIf="getCountryss()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="onSelectCountry($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="Country">
            <option value="0">Select Country</option>
            <option *ngFor="let Country of getCountryss()" value= {{Country.id}}>{{Country.name}}</option>
            <option value="others">Other- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedCountry == 'others'">
            <label for="name">Enter Category:</label>
            <input type="text" #category class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "userCategory" (change)="CountryTextAreaFilled(userCategory)">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ProviderType">Type:</label>
      <select *ngIf="type" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" (change)="onSelectProviderType($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="type">
          <option value="0">Select Type</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of type" value= {{type.id}}>{{type.name}}</option>
        <option value="others">Other- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedType == 'others'">
            <label for="name">Enter Type:</label>
            <input type="text" #type class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "userType" [disabled]="providerInputStatus" (change)="CountryTextAreaFilled(userType)">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="State">State:</label>
            <select *ngIf="type" [(ngModel)]="selectedState" (change)="onSelectState($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="State">
            <option value="0">Select Classifcation</option>
            <option *ngFor="let State of State" value= {{State.id}}>{{State.name}}</option>
            <option value="others">Other- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedState == 'others'">
            <label for="name">Enter State:</label>
            <input type="text" #State class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "userState" [disabled]="categoryInputStatus" (change)="CountryTextAreaFilled(userState)">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Location">Location:</label>
                  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation" class="form-control input-lg" id="Location">
                  <option value="0">Select Location</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let Location of Location" value= {{Location.id}}>{{Location.name}}</option>
                  <option value="others">Other- Please Specify Below</option>
            </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedLocation == 'others'">
            <label for="name">Enter Location:</label>
            <input type="text" #Location class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "userLocation" [disabled]="specializationInputStatus" (change)="CountryTextAreaFilled(userState)">
</div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveCountry(userCategory, userType, userState, userLocation, selectedCountry, selectedType, selectedState, selectedLocation)">Submit</button>

      <br>
      <h3 *ngIf = "isAdded" >{{confirmationString}}</h3>


<a routerLink = "/angular"> < back</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous but I will try to help you out.

If your server is expecting String/text values then you need to handle it in the frontend and send it what it expects. So you should have to set logic to transform to string your numeric  the function:

```
 saveCountry(userCategory, userType, userState, userLocation, selectedCountry, selectedType, selectedState, selectedLocation) {

    if(selectedCountry!=='others') {
      selectedCountry = selectedCountry.toString(); 
    } else {
    selectedCountry = userState; 
}
```

and so on for the rest of values.

To get the string value you have to set it in the value of the option element and then that value will be assigned to the selectedCountry model when selecting it from the dropdown:

```
<select *ngIf="getCountryss()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change)="onSelectCountry($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="Country">
            <option value="0">Select Country</option>
            <option *ngFor="let Country of getCountryss()" value="{{Country.name}}">{{Country.name}}</option>
            <option value="others">Other- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
```

Now you will have access to that country string in your saveCountry(...) function.

Comment: Yes, I figured that I would have to handle it on the frontend. The problem is "selectedCountry" has the id value from the dropdown list. The toString will still be the id. I need the name.  The reason I chose to store the id in the first place was because that's the only value I could see in the $event.